# javascript regular expression for dimension

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regular expression to check for valid dimension 
length x breadth x height in javascript.

For e.g. 90.49 x 34.93 x 40.64

Sample code I intend to use:

---

```
var dimensionRegex = 'the regular expression for validation dimension string';
var tempDimension  = 'dimension string input by the user';

if (dimensionRegex.test(tempDimension)) {
    return true;
} else { 
    return false;   
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can just do `return dimensionRegex.test(tempDimension);`, no need for the `if` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use regexps for that? You could just `split('x')` the string and then strip leading/trailing space from the array elements. Then you `parseInt(elem, 10)` the array elements and you have what you need.

However, if you actually want to validate the format:

```
var dimValid = /^\d+(\.\d+)? x \d+(\.\d+)? x \d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(tempDimension);
```

This will match `number x number x number`.